# Accuracy of the result question short?

Tags: numerical-methods

We have 1/(4,5) .

When we do the divison,what accuracy does the result have?

Comment: I assume you mean $1/4.5$.

Comment: Explain a little more the problem.

Comment: The numerator has one significant figure and the denominator has two significant figures, right?  And you're asking how many significant figures the quotient has?

Comment: It has to be that,I thought it could also mean,find the number of the correct digits but in that case I couldnt use Δx≤(1/2)*10^{-n}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about significance arithmetic.  When [dividing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_arithmetic#Multiplication_and_division_using_significance_arithmetic) numbers, "the result is rounded to the number of significant figures in the [operand] with the least significant figures."  Assuming that your dividend really is $1$ (and not, say, $1.0$), then your quotient should be rounded to one significant figure.  That is, $1/4.5\approx 0$.  But if your dividend is, say, $1.0$, then  your quotient should be rounded to two significant figures.  That is, $1/4.5\approx 0.2$.

Comment: I assume you are not talking about [computer arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_arithmetic).

Comment: It is also possible, though, that 1 is an exact value, with infinite significant figures. In which case the quotient should be rounded to two significant figures. It is hard to tell from the question, though.

Comment: @wgrenard, yes, but if so, then it would also be possible that $4.5$ also is an exact value.  The question is vague.